# reduce bandwidth consumption from downloading yum updates

Tags: yum, repository, cluster, bandwidth, mirror

I have several machines (7) running fedora and would like to reduce the amount of external bandwidth I am consuming.  I see that there were several attempts to setup mirrors, but those projects seem dead.  I've used a squid proxy before, but that also has issues with different mirrors and ssl.  Finally, I could run a clustered FS so that way any package that is downloaded on one will be available on another and if it should go offline, it will automatically re-sync when it comes back online.

Is there a simpler to configure and more correct option than using something like glusterfs?

Comment: I'm familiar with Debian packaging, not yum, so I'm making this a comment, not an answer. Trying to share the downloaded files using glusterfs (or even just NFS) sounds like trouble to me, and much more work than setting up a proxy of some kind, for the same gain, honestly. There are, as you say, purpose-built proxy servers for this (at least there are for Debian repos) but using a squid proxy should work perfectly well too. I don't know why you would have had issues with that. We use both purpose-built proxies (apt-proxy) and squid proxies for this purpose on different projects. Works fine.

Comment: Doesn't [setting up your own mirror](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/Mirroring) work for you?

Comment: A mirror would take up too much space.  I have 5 GB that I think should be sufficient to allocate.

Comment: I will give squid another try, but I will have to disable the fastestmirror plugin when I'm on my home network.  That can be done with a NetworkManager-dispatcher script.

Comment: I have squid working, it wasn't much effort and I am relatively happy with the results.  I do throttle bandwidth through tc based on protocol and some other things, and I will eventually look to see to throttle it further at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

For part of your question and for completeness, if you only wanted to reduce/limit the bandwidth consumption for yum, there is [the throttle option that can be either enabled globally or for a specific plugin or repo](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/671423)

There are other settings that you can leverage to use more of the yum cache and do not refresh repository metadata as often by default. See e.g. this fedora forum thread for more hints: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/31808/how-to-make-yum-consume-less-traffic/

Although the closest option for your intended use case would probably be a yum proxy that you setup on one of your boxes, that only downloads the packages that you request and can provide them to other boxes. A short search shows this exact thing doesn't seem to exist so you might need to write it yourself. [It exists for Mageia, it is called urpmi-proxy](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Urpmi-proxy).
With a little bit of knowledge of apache you should be able to adapt it to Fedora, see also the explanation [What does it actually do? How does it actually work?](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Urpmi-proxy#What_does_it_actually_do.3F_How_does_it_actually_work.3F)

The code is located in our git: http://gitweb.mageia.org/software/rpm/urpmi-proxy/

**Some related information:**

- https://serverfault.com/questions/559211/yum-repo-server-as-archive-cache
- https://serverfault.com/questions/142830/caching-proxy-for-yum-and-debian-repositories
- http://serverascode.com/2014/03/29/squid-cache-yum.html