# How do I turn a local yum repository into a local satellite for many other repositories

Tags: linux, rhel, package-management, yum, repository

I am not sure I am asking this question in the best way.  I am doing my best to ask it in the clearest way possible.

I would like to build a local (to my cluster) yum repository server such that I can add this yum repository to my servers within my infrastructure and then, aggregate all external yum repositories through this repository.

The end goal is that the local yum repository becomes the source of the software which should be present in my internal cluster.  As such, I can control the available package versions for my cluster in a single source.

I would appreciate any assistance and knowledge here.

Thank you

Comment: I've provided the relevant links for that already in another related thread: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197066/83329
Even when you don't want your master repository node to act as a proxy on behalf of the other nodes, this would still work out. Also all available options (manually creating a repo via createrepo, caching proxy server, dedicated repo management tools, centralised configuration management/deployment including repo management ...) are explained in the linked threads. If you feel a use case is missing, please expand your initial description.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is a cronned job to wget a tree off a public repo box out in the world (mirror.centos.org anyone?) and have it mirror it all in /var/www/html/reponame .

Later on, strongly consider looking into the cobbler project from redhat.  It's a great repo manager, and later on will help you build repos into distros, glue that with profiles to kickstarts, and like magic you'll have a complete mirror and install server.  But it's more than the 20 minutes a cronned wget script will take, so ... tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put all repos in one server(better a cluster)
and then "share" the repo,using ftp,or http.

Comment: Not really useful as an answer, no links to documentation nor an example. Next time better go for a comment ...